# Creating Text file using android emulator

Tags: android

I am making a handwriting recognizer using android emulator , I have coordinates stored in an arraylist , What i want is that i need to store the coordinates on a text file in my computer's harddisk so that the text file can be later read by an external tool kit like hidden markov model ( that text file will be my training data ) . How can i create a TEXT FILE on my HARD DISK and make it editable and readable to users and external softwares

Thanks

Comment: I think its not possible to create this kind of file on Harddisk while running app on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create files on your local disk from the emulator directly, but you can copy files from it with `adb pull`. eg:

```
$ adb pull /default.prop
17 KB/s (118 bytes in 0.006s)
$ cat default.prop
#
# ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES
#
ro.secure=1
ro.allow.mock.location=0
ro.debuggable=0
persist.service.adb.enable=0
```

You can also use `adb push` to copy files *to* the emulator.

(adb is part of the Android SDK)